# Excel Dynamic Hyperkink using Cell Value as part of Address

Tags: excel, dynamic, hyperlink, excel-formula, string-concatenation

I have a column of part numbers which I would like to associate with a column of links to their corresponding autocad drawings. The drawings are on a server, I would like to be able to insert the part number into the file path.

**My attempt:**

```
=HYPERLINK(\\servername\folderofparts\partprefix\['Lists for Calculations'!B8].dwg","Link")
```

where cell `B8` within the sheet Lists for Calculations contains the name of the part.

Answer (score 0):

try,

```
=HYPERLINK("\\servername\folderofparts\partprefix\" & 'Lists for Calculations'!B8 & ".dwg", "Link")
```

tbh, it's a little unclear whether the square brackets were intended to be part of the filename or not. I removed them above.